# How to get expected process name from executable path in .desktop file

Tags: ubuntu, process, .desktop

I'm reading through the .desktop files found in /usr/share/applications and it appears SOME don't share the same process name as the executable file (most do).

Is there a way to find that the process name will be?

Example:

Chromes .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Google Chrome
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=google-chrome
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=application/pdf;application/rdf+xml;application/rss+xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xhtml_xml;application/xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;image/webp;text/html;text/xml;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;
```

When I run `pidof google-chrome-stable` it returns null.

But when I run `pidof chrome` it returns all the PID's

879321 879303 805004 755066 693852 693837 693796 688198 624316 624289 3194 2788 2762 2734 2685 2677 2641 2637 2620 2613 2611 2601

Is there a better way to find the PID?

Please note I MUST search from information found in the .desktop file. (long story)

Thanks

Comment: Your question is fuzzy to me. You are stating that same command returns null and a set of PIDs...

Comment: Its a typo!! I've changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the `Exec` line, it might be a shell script running another executable or it might be a link or even an executable spawning another.

I'm not sure how you can get the information only from `desktop` file however one solution might be to run it...

*Note that I don't have google-chrome so I use chromium in my example.*

```bsh
# Extract the command from desktop file
$ CMD=$(grep -Po "(?<=^Exec=).+\s" /usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop)
$ echo $CMD
/usr/bin/chromium

# Run it
$ CMD &

# Get the PID
$ PID=$(echo $!)
$ echo $PID
5146

# Get process name from PID
$ ps --no-header -p $PID -o comm
chromium

# Get the complete command line + arguments
ps --no-header -p $PID -o cmd
/usr/lib/chromium/chromium --show-component-extension-options --enable-gpu-rasterization

# Terminate process
kill -SIGTERM $PID
```

Answer (score 1):

What likely happens here is that the initial executable uses an `exec...()` system call(*) to replace all its code by a new executable and parameters and the very same process id will correspond to that new code and be listed as such by `ps`, so that the initial executable disappears from the process list. This is often used to set up an environment for another executable.

(*) Or the `exec` builtin if it is a shell script